# UserData on AWS Cloudformation not getting deployed on EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cloudformation

I am trying to bootstrap an EC2 with tools like *kubectl* and *nodejs*. However, I am unable to execute the UserData. Could someone help me out with the script I have below:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Part 1 - Build a webapp stack with CloudFormation

Resources:
  WebAppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      ImageId: ami-074cce78125f09d61
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebAppSecurityGroup
      UserData: 
        Fn::Base64: |
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            yum install nodejs -y
            curl -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl

  WebAppSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [webapp-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  WebAppEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      InstanceId: !Ref WebAppInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [webapp-eip, dev]]

  RootRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"

  RolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: root
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RootRole

  RootInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RootRole

  candidateUser:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
    Properties:
      UserName: candidate # give a name to this user
      LoginProfile: # specify a password for this user
        Password: DTelek0m
        PasswordResetRequired: false # make this user to set a new password on next sign-in
      Path: '/'
      ManagedPolicyArns: # list of ARNs of IAM managed policies that you want to attach to the user
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/EC2InstanceConnect

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !Sub http://${WebAppEIP}
    Description: WebApp URL
```

EC2 comes without any issues but I am not able to install software packages on top of that. I tried deploying *nodejs*, *nginx*, *kubectl* so far.

Comment: Look at system log and cloud-init logs per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904095/how-to-check-whether-my-user-data-passing-to-ec2-instance-working-or-not).

Comment: @jarmod No logs concerning UserData.

Comment: Your `UserData` does not install any of kubectl and tomcat. So its not clear what exactly is the issue.

Comment: By system log, I'm referring to Monitor and Troubleshoot > Get System Log from within the EC2 console. It *will* show boot time logs. Add `echo` statements, if needed, to your userdata and relaunch.

Comment: @Marcin Have updated the script to make it more clear. I am trying to install kubectl and nodejs.

Comment: @Salam Ok, so what is the problem? You still haven't explained the issue. Are you getting any errors? What exactly is happening?

Comment: @jarmodGetting accessing the logs through Monitor and Troubleshoot > Get System Log helped.

Answer (score 1):

Working solution:

The problem identified is that the curl installation was missing.

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Description: Part 1 - Build a webapp stack with CloudFormation

Resources:
  WebAppInstance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      AvailabilityZone: us-east-2a
      ImageId: ami-074cce78125f09d61
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SecurityGroupIds:
        - !Ref WebAppSecurityGroup
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          !Sub |
            #!/bin/bash -xe
            sudo yum install curl
            curl -o kubectl https://amazon-eks.s3.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/1.21.2/2021-07-05/bin/linux/amd64/kubectl
            sudo install -o root -g root -m 0755 kubectl /usr/local/bin/kubectl

  WebAppSecurityGroup:
    Type: AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup
    Properties:
      GroupName: !Join ["-", [webapp-security-group, dev]]
      GroupDescription: "Allow HTTP/HTTPS and SSH inbound and outbound traffic"
      SecurityGroupIngress:
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 80
          ToPort: 80
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 443
          ToPort: 443
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0
        - IpProtocol: tcp
          FromPort: 22
          ToPort: 22
          CidrIp: 0.0.0.0/0

  WebAppEIP:
    Type: AWS::EC2::EIP
    Properties:
      Domain: vpc
      InstanceId: !Ref WebAppInstance
      Tags:
        - Key: Name
          Value: !Join ["-", [webapp-eip, dev]]

  RootRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - ec2.amazonaws.com
            Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
      Path: "/"

  RolePolicies:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyName: root
      PolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action: "*"
            Resource: "*"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RootRole

  RootInstanceProfile:
    Type: AWS::IAM::InstanceProfile
    Properties:
      Path: "/"
      Roles:
        - !Ref RootRole

  candidateUser:
    Type: 'AWS::IAM::User'
    Properties:
      UserName: candidate # give a name to this user
      LoginProfile: # specify a password for this user
        Password: DTelek0m
        PasswordResetRequired: false # make this user to set a new password on next sign-in
      Path: '/'
      ManagedPolicyArns: # list of ARNs of IAM managed policies that you want to attach to the user
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2FullAccess
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/EC2InstanceConnect

Outputs:
  WebsiteURL:
    Value: !Sub http://${WebAppEIP}
    Description: WebApp URL
```