# AWS userdata behaviour

Tags: amazon-web-services, user-data

Below is my userdata

```
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo yum update -y
    sudo amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
    sudo systemctl start nginx
    sudo touch /tmp/file2.txt
```

nginx is installed but not started, I want to understand why it is not started, can someone please help me here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check whether my user data passing to EC2 instance is working or not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904095/how-to-check-whether-my-user-data-passing-to-ec2-instance-is-working-or-not)

Comment: What is in the log file? `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`

Comment: User data scripts are run as the root user, so no need for sudo.

Comment: Can you then run it when you log into the machine?

Comment: some how it is working now,  ```                                                                       #!/bin/bash
yum update -y
amazon-linux-extras install nginx1
systemctl start nginx
touch /tmp/file2.txt                                                                                                                                                               ```