# How to set cpu_manager_policy to static in eks managed nodegroup.?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-ec2, amazon-eks, eksctl

Hi i have been trying to do cpu pinning in my eks cluster. i have used amazon linux latest release, and my eks version is 1.22 . i have created a launch template where i have used this user data mentioned below.

```
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="//"
MIME-Version: 1.0

--//

#!/bin/bash

set -o xtrace

/etc/eks/bootstrap.sh $CLUSTER_NAME 

sleep 2m

yum update -y

sudo rm /var/lib/kubelet/cpu_manager_state

sudo chmod 777 kubelet.service

sudo cat > /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service <<EOF

[Unit]
Description=Kubernetes Kubelet
Documentation=https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes
After=docker.service iptables-restore.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
ExecStartPre=/sbin/iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT -w 5
ExecStart=/usr/bin/kubelet --cloud-provider aws \
    --image-credential-provider-config /etc/eks/ecr-credential-provider/ecr- 
   credential-provider-config \
    --image-credential-provider-bin-dir /etc/eks/ecr-credential-provider \
    --cpu-manager-policy=static \
    --kube-reserved=cpu=0.5,memory=1Gi,ephemeral-storage=0.5Gi \
    --system-reserved=cpu=0.5,memory=1Gi,ephemeral-storage=0.5Gi \
    --config /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json \
    --kubeconfig /var/lib/kubelet/kubeconfig \
    --container-runtime docker \
    --network-plugin cni $KUBELET_ARGS $KUBELET_EXTRA_ARGS

Restart=always
RestartSec=5
KillMode=process

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

EOF

sudo chmod 644 kubelet.service

sudo systemctl daemon-reload

sudo systemctl stop kubelet

sudo systemctl start kubelet


--//
```

after creating the template i have used it on the eks nodegroup creation. after waititng a while i am getting this error on the eks dashboard.

Health issues (1)
NodeCreationFailure Instances failed to join the kubernetes cluster .

and i have get into that ec2 instance and used the following command to view kubectl logs

```
$journalctl -f -u kubelet
```

the output is

```
[ec2-user@ip-10.100.11.111 kubelet]$ journalctl -f -u kubelet

-- Logs begin at Thu 2022-04-21 07:27:50 UTC. --

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.199868   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="3b513cfa- 
441d-4e25-9441-093b4c2ed548" containerName="efs-plugin" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.244811   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="3b513cfa- 
441d-4e25-9441-093b4c2ed548" containerName="csi-provisioner" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.305206   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="3b513cfa- 
441d-4e25-9441-093b4c2ed548" containerName="liveness-probe" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.335744   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="de537700- 
f5ac-4039-a151-110ddf27d140" containerName="efs-plugin" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.388843   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="de537700- 
f5ac-4039-a151-110ddf27d140" containerName="csi-driver-registrar" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.464789   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="de537700- 
f5ac-4039-a151-110ddf27d140" containerName="liveness-probe" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.545206   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="a2f09d0d- 
69f5-4bb7-82bb-edfa86cb87e2" containerName="kube-controller" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.633078   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="3ec70fe1- 
3680-4e3c-bcfa-81f80ebe20b0" containerName="kube-proxy" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:31:21 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: I0421 
07:31:21.696852   12225 state_mem.go:80] "Updated desired CPUSet" podUID="adbd9bef- 
c4e0-4bd1-a6a6-52530ad4bea3" containerName="aws-node" cpuSet="0-7"

Apr 21 07:46:12 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: E0421 
07:46:12.424801   12225 certificate_manager.go:488] kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving: 
certificate request was not signed: timed out waiting for the condition

Apr 21 08:01:16 ip-10.100.11.111.us-west-2.compute.internal kubelet[12225]: E0421 
08:01:16.810385   12225 certificate_manager.go:488] kubernetes.io/kubelet-serving: 
certificate request was not signed: timed out waiting for the condition
```

this was the output..

But before using this method i have also tried another method, where i have created a node group and then i have created an ami from one of the nodes in that nodegroup.. then modified the kubelet.service file and removed the old cpu_manager_state file.. then the i have used this image to create the nodegroup. Then it worked fine But the problem was i am unable to get into the pods running in those nodes and also i am unable to get the logs of the pods running there. and strangely if i use
$kubectl get nodes -o wide
in the output i was not getting the internal and external both ip addresses.
so i moved on to using the userdata instead of this method.

kindly give me instructions to create a managed nodegroup with cpu_manager_state as static policy for eks cluster .

Answer (score 3):

I had the same question. I added the following `userdata` script to my launch template

### User data script

```sh
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="==MYBOUNDARY=="

--==MYBOUNDARY==
Content-Type: text/x-shellscript; charset="us-ascii"

#!/bin/bash
yum install -y jq

set -o xtrace

cp /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json.back

jq '. += { "cpuManagerPolicy":"static"}' /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json.back > /etc/kubernetes/kubelet/kubelet-config.json

--==MYBOUNDARY==--
```

### Verification

You can verify the change took effect using `kubectl`:

```sh
# start a k8s API proxy
$ kubectl proxy

# get the node name
$ kubectl get nodes

# get kubelet config
$ curl -sSL "http://localhost:8001/api/v1/nodes/<<node_name>>/proxy/configz"
```

I got the solution from this guide: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/eks-worker-nodes-image-cache/. However, I could not make the `sed` command properly work so I used `jq` instead.

### Logs

If you can `ssh` into the node, you can check the userdata logs in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log` - See https://stackoverflow.com/a/32460849/4400704

### CPU pinning

I have a pod with a status QoS `Guarantee` (CPU limit and requested = 2) and I can verify it has two CPU reserved

```
$ cat /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset/cpuset.cpus
2,10
```

Answer (score 1):

CPU manager policy is only supported in [EKS since K8s version `1.23`](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-now-supports-kubernetes-1-23/). As you mentioned you're using EKS `1.22` I suppose, you can't set the CPU manager policy to `static` unless you upgrade to at least `1.23` as this kubelet config option is (most probably) not supported on your EKS nodes.

As documented in the [K8s Feature Gates table](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/containers/amazon-eks-now-supports-kubernetes-1-23/), `CPUManagerPolicyOptions` Feature Gate entered `Beta` in `1.23` only and turned stable/GA since [K8s `1.26`](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2022/12/27/cpumanager-ga/).