# AWS: user data script for EC2 instance is not executing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a script for EC2 instance User Data. I verified after EC2 instance is READY

```
#!/bin/bash
yum update -y
yum install nginx
service nginx start
echo '<h4> Welcome to AWS</h4>' >> /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
```

If I login into EC2 instance and if i try to execute the above commands one-by-one and then we can see the results. But not executing same script when i use inside User Data while EC2 start up. Please someone can suggest me on this? did i miss any setting/configurations ?

## Logs

```
Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'init' at Sun, 11 Jun 2023 12:12:40 +0000. Up 8.80 seconds.
ci-info: ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Net device info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: | Device |  Up  |           Address           |      Mask     | Scope  |     Hw-Address    |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: |  enX0  | True |         10.80.2.254         | 255.255.255.0 | global | 0a:56:b9:5f:1f:30 |
ci-info: |  enX0  | True | fe80::856:b9ff:fe5f:1f30/64 |       .       |  link  | 0a:56:b9:5f:1f:30 |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |          127.0.0.1          |   255.0.0.0   |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: |   lo   | True |           ::1/128           |       .       |  host  |         .         |
ci-info: +--------+------+-----------------------------+---------------+--------+-------------------+
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++Route IPv4 info+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination |  Gateway  |     Genmask     | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   0   |   0.0.0.0   | 10.80.2.1 |     0.0.0.0     |    enX0   |   UG  |
ci-info: |   1   |  10.80.0.2  | 10.80.2.1 | 255.255.255.255 |    enX0   |  UGH  |
ci-info: |   2   |  10.80.2.0  |  0.0.0.0  |  255.255.255.0  |    enX0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   3   |  10.80.2.1  |  0.0.0.0  | 255.255.255.255 |    enX0   |   UH  |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+-----------+-----------------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: +++++++++++++++++++Route IPv6 info+++++++++++++++++++
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: | Route | Destination | Gateway | Interface | Flags |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
ci-info: |   1   |  fe80::/64  |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   3   |    local    |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
ci-info: |   4   |  multicast  |    ::   |    enX0   |   U   |
ci-info: +-------+-------------+---------+-----------+-------+
Generating public/private ed25519 key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:E6rTH/qkWkm+1MnibB19PEAF/fCiUHoGNlD5umOU9Cs root@ip-10-80-2-254.ap-south-1.compute.internal
The key's randomart image is:
+--[ED25519 256]--+
|      .o...+.    |
|        = o o    |
|       ..B   +   |
|       .+.= . o  |
|      o.SO + .   |
|     = +=o+ +    |
|    o Bo*o o .   |
|     *.BE..      |
|    .o*ooo       |
+----[SHA256]-----+
Generating public/private ecdsa key pair.
Your identification has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
Your public key has been saved in /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
The key fingerprint is:
SHA256:OeTafm90Z9JyrM+pLB9ETVTC/wLgXvA5seUizr7LCC4 root@ip-10-80-2-254.ap-south-1.compute.internal
The key's randomart image is:
+---[ECDSA 256]---+
|             .ooo|
|          o . =. |
|        .. + B o |
|       o .o X . .|
|        S+ o = o.|
|       o .+ o = B|
|      o .. . o O |
|    E. o oo.o o..|
|     .. o.+=++.oo|
+----[SHA256]-----+
Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:config' at Sun, 11 Jun 2023 12:12:44 +0000. Up 12.79 seconds.
Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 running 'modules:final' at Sun, 11 Jun 2023 12:12:46 +0000. Up 14.11 seconds.
Amazon Linux 2023 repository                     24 MB/s |  14 MB     00:00
Amazon Linux 2023 Kernel Livepatch repository   495 kB/s | 156 kB     00:00
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:02 ago on Sun Jun 11 12:12:56 2023.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package               Arch     Version                     Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
 nginx                 x86_64   1:1.24.0-1.amzn2023.0.1     amazonlinux    32 k
Installing dependencies:
 generic-logos-httpd   noarch   18.0.0-12.amzn2023.0.3      amazonlinux    19 k
 gperftools-libs       x86_64   2.9.1-1.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux   309 k
 libunwind             x86_64   1.4.0-5.amzn2023.0.2        amazonlinux    66 k
 nginx-core            x86_64   1:1.24.0-1.amzn2023.0.1     amazonlinux   586 k
 nginx-filesystem      noarch   1:1.24.0-1.amzn2023.0.1     amazonlinux   9.0 k
 nginx-mimetypes       noarch   2.1.49-3.amzn2023.0.3       amazonlinux    21 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  7 Packages

Total download size: 1.0 M
Installed size: 3.4 M
Is this ok [y/N]: Operation aborted.
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start nginx.service
Failed to start nginx.service: Unit nginx.service not found.
/var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts/part-001: line 5: /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html: No such file or directory
2023-06-11 12:12:58,743 - cc_scripts_user.py[WARNING]: Failed to run module scripts-user (scripts in /var/lib/cloud/instance/scripts)
2023-06-11 12:12:58,744 - util.py[WARNING]: Running module scripts-user (<module 'cloudinit.config.cc_scripts_user' from '/usr/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cloudinit/config/cc_scripts_user.py'>) failed
Cloud-init v. 22.2.2 finished at Sun, 11 Jun 2023 12:12:59 +0000. Datasource DataSourceEc2.  Up 27.18 seconds
```

Comment: Check the user-data logs to see if there are any errors https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904095/how-to-check-whether-my-user-data-passing-to-ec2-instance-is-working

Comment: What is in `/var/log/cloud-init-output.log`?

Comment: Actually while installing Nginx , it will ask one question i.e. 
Is this ok [y/N]: Y ---> here we have to select manually "Y". But when we doing through EC2 UserData, this operation aborted. that is log is saying. Logs i attached @John Rotenstein in the question. Please suggest

Answer (score 2):

You have the `-y` flag already in your `yum update` command, so that it doesn't stop and give you the `[y/N]` prompt. You just need to do the same thing with your `yum install` command:

```
yum install -y nginx
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see what exactly went wrong with the execution of a User Script on an EC2, SSH into the instance and navigate to /var/log. Then cat cloud-init-output.log, which will show you all the messages generated while the script was being executed.