# AWS cloudformation: Fn:Base64:: Unable to handle special characters

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have created a cloud formation script

```
# in mumbai region (working)
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fcbc9ed97efe271e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-fc2df495
      KeyName: sant-test
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64:
          Fn::Sub: |
          #!/bin/bash -xe
          yum update -y
          echo somenthing:khskhsdh >> test.txt
```

this is throwing error at `echo somenthing:khskhsdh >> test.txt`

[image]

i get error something like:

[image]

How to handle special characters

Comment: What's the exact error message and where is it coming from?

Comment: The error you show just means your template has incorrect syntax in it

Comment: @Paolo, it comes from cloudformation designer when clicking `validate template` button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked up all my templates and found an example that works 100%:

```
Resources:
  MyNewEC2Instance:
    Type: AWS::EC2::Instance
    Properties:
      ImageId: ami-0fcbc9ed97efe271e
      InstanceType: t2.micro
      SubnetId: subnet-fc2df495
      KeyName: sant-test
      UserData:
        Fn::Base64: |-
          #!/bin/bash
          yum update -y
          echo somenthing:khskhsdh >> test.txt
```

The `Fn::Sub:` in the question is redundant and causing an error.

Comment: Hi where can i check the logs to check whether the bash script got executed successfully

Comment: Sure, see here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15904095/how-to-check-whether-my-user-data-passing-to-ec2-instance-is-working

Comment: @Santhosh that is a different question. if this question has been resolved by this answer, consider upvoting/accepting this answer