# AWS EC2 `ssh: connect to host ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused` only if `user-data` uses `systemctl` commands

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, user-data, ec2-userdata

### AWS Setup

I have a AWS EC2 instance running with:

- `t4g.nano`
- `al2023-ami-2023.3.20240122.0-kernel-6.1-arm64` (AL2023)
- a Security Group setup to allow SSH from my personal IP address
- sshd is installed & running
- a valid ssh key/value pair assigned
- a Public IP address assigned (so I can connect to it)

### Local Setup

I am running on MacOS v13.6.2 with ssh:

```bash
$ ssh -V 
OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
```

### Problem

#### With No User Data

If my EC2 instance does not have any `user-data`, I am able to connect to the instance using ssh. Example ssh:

```bash
$ ssh -i "my-key-pair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com
```

This connects just fine.

#### With User Data

If my EC2 instance has a `user-data` script *with certain commands*, then I get the following error:

```bash
$ ssh -vvv -i "my-key-pair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com   

OpenSSH_9.0p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/dj/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/dj/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/* matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 54: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/Users/dj/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/Users/dj/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did not resolve; disabling
debug1: Connecting to ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22.
ssh: connect to host ec2-{ip}.compute-1.amazonaws.com port 22: Connection refused
```

It is difficult to track down what commands causes this issue, but here is what I know so far:

- If my script contains anything using `systemctl`, then it causes the ssh connection to be refused:

  ```bash
  # example, I install docker in `user-data`
  yum install -y docker

  service docker start

  systemctl enable docker.service
  systemctl enable containerd.service
  ```

  - This will cause the connection refused.

#### Question

I am not an ssh or scripting expert. Why does my `user-data` script's call to `systemctl` suddenly cause my ssh to break?

Comment: You can check the log of your user data script: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15904095/12326605

Comment: @ArpitJain, I did check the logs the best I could. `cloud-init.log` does not contain the `user-data` script output and `cloud-init-output.log` is only accessible once inside the instance (which I can't get into without ssh). Would it be possible to try some kind of shared storage to persist the logs between startups?

Comment: @DJHouse you could try to setup Systems Manager Session manager access to the instance and access that way. It doesn't require SSH and you will be able to access the instance and check the logs. Also, you're using nano instance, so it's possible that docker installation is taking longer, or it break something (check CPU usage, credits, but it's very likely that those 512MB RAM from nano instance are fully used)

Comment: Have you run these commands in an EC2 of the same spec that you spin up yourself?  You've got 512k of RAM.  When EC2's of any size run out of memory connectivity is poor at best.

Comment: @Caldazar, I will try to setup SMS today if I can and try to view the logs. 

@stdunbar, I would be surprised if memory was an issue. If I start up a blank `t4g.nano` with nothing installed, then ssh into it and run the `user-data` script directly from the terminal, everything works just fine and I can download my docker image and run it.